# Get background color after CSS filters

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-filters

I have a div, filled with a background color.
With Javascript i dinamically change the hue, saturation and lightness filters using 3 wrappers around the div, each one with a filter.

```
   <div class="filterHue">
      <div class="filterSaturation">
         <div class="filterLightness">
            <div class="baseColor"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

How I can get the resulting background color of the `baseColor` div after the filters, in order to apply that color to multiple text elements?

The only solution that i came up with, is to wrap the text elements the same way as the div, but i think that is a overkill to have too many filters on the page, i prefer another solution if it is possible.

Comment: What about [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)? Also, please post your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the computed color from the div. But you can use javascript to calculate the filters effects on the base color. Check out this library - https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor

It has methods such as `lighten`, `saturate` and `spin`

Comment: This worked well, but the colors are a bit different. (i was using not a single color, but gradients) I entirely removed filters and used this library to calculate colors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  I thought that [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) might help.  But I don't think it takes the resolved background color into consideration.

The below code still outputs:

> rgb(0, 0, 255)

```js
var e = document.querySelectorAll("div.test")[0];

alert(window.getComputedStyle(e, null)["background-color"]);
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```